# Function inside a model, sum of other models matching date

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a invoice system for my project and I have reached a point where I can't figure the logic out to create this. I just want all of the invoices I enter to be saved to a invoice_complete model with a imported date. I don't know if this is possible through the model directly or if I will have to do some messing around in views. I create the billing period and then input 'invoice' in that particular period, then I want to send all of those to an invoice complete to actually send a price to the user.

```
class Bill_Period(models.Model):
    start_date              = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_date                = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.start_date)

class Service_Entry(models.Model):
    date_of_service         = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now(),blank=True)
    agency_to_bill          = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True)
    therapy_completed       = models.ForeignKey('Service', blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
            return unicode(self.agency_to_bill)


class Invoice_Complete(models.Model):
    date                    = # bill_period
    billed_to               = models.CharField(max_length="50", blank=True)
    total                   = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    paid                    = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
            return u"%s %s" % (self.date, self.billed_to)
```

I need a queryset like this to get what I need, I just don't know where to use it for it to work.

```
def get_cost():
    invoice_detail  = Service_Entry.objects.filter(date_of_service__year=year,
                                            date_of_service__month=month,
                                            agency_to_bill=billed_to)
    c               = invoice_detail.aggregate(t = Sum('therapy_completed__cost')).values()[0]
    return c
```

To give you a better idea of what I'm trying to accomplish, I was using this view but it would always save and never update so I could not use it.

```
def invoice_detail(request, month, year):
    current_user    = request.user
    invoice_detail  = Service_Entry.objects.filter(date_of_service__year=year,
                                             date_of_service__month=month,
                                             agency_to_bill=current_user)
    c               = invoice_detail.aggregate(t = Sum('therapy_completed__cost')).values()[0]
    ic = Invoice_Complete(date=month,billed_to=current_user,total=c)
    ic.save()
```

***edit
Ran into another issue that I do not know how to solve. I basically need a query inside a loop.

```
#invoice-list.html
<table width=100%>
        {% for period in span %}
        <tr><td><a href="{% url 'invoice-detail' period.start_date|date:"Y" period.start_date|date:"m" %}">{{ period.start_date | date:"M Y" }}</a></td>
        <td></td> #need total for month looped
        <td></td> #need paid true/false for month looped
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
</table>

#views.py
def invoicelist(request):
        span = Bill_Period.objects.all()
        return render_to_response('invoice-list.html', {'span': span})


def InvoiceDetail(request, month, year): 
        current_user    = request.user
        invoice_detail  = invoice.objects.filter(date_of_service__year=year,date_of_service__month=month,agency_to_bill=current_user)
        c               = invoice_detail.aggregate(t = Sum('therapy_completed__cost')).values()[0]
        if Invoice_Complete.objects.filter(date_month=month,date_year=year,billed_to=current_user).exists():
                ic = Invoice_Complete.objects.get(date_month=month, date_year=year, billed_to=current_user)
                ic = ic.total + c
                ic.save()
        else:
                ic = Invoice_Complete(date_month=month,date_year=year,billed_to=current_user,total=c)
                ic.save()

       return render_to_response('invoice-detail.html', {'invoice_detail': invoice_detail,
                                                         'current_user': current_user,
                                                         'month': month,
                                                          'c': c,})
```

Answer (score 0):

> it would always save and never update so I could not use it.

Because you are never updating it. You are always saving it.

```
ic = Invoice_Complete(date=month,billed_to=current_user,total=c)
ic.save()
```

will always create a new object. If you want to update existing values you have to first get it from the database like this -

```
if Invoice_Complete.objects.filter(date=month,billed_to=current_user).exists():
    ic = Invoice_Complete.objects.get(date=month,billed_to=current_user)
    ic = ic.total + c
    ic.save()
else: # this is a new entry
    ic = Invoice_Complete(date=month,billed_to=current_user,total=c)
    ic.save()
```

Or a more shorter version -

```
ic, created = Invoice_Complete.objects.get_or_create(date=month,billed_to=current_user)
if created: # this is a new entry
    ic.total = c
else: # this is an old entry so update it
    ic.total = ic.total + c
ic.save() # call save. will save or update as necessary
```

Comment: much appreciated. I was not aware `.exists()` existed. That worked for me, unfortunately `get_or_create` is not available in my django version. I ran into one more issue that I was hoping you could point me in the right direction on. I feel like my data is already structured incorrectly and it will prevent me from running the query I need. I edited it in, attn to the html page for description.